# Unable to edit geometry into database using PostGIS connection in Civil 3D

Tags: postgis, postgresql, workflow, civil3d, map3d

I have prepared a set of tables (in PostgreSQL) in database with unique geometry types (point, line, polygons) for survey work. I am using Autodesk Civil 3D to edit the geometries in the tables but they are not getting saved in the database (which is feature source). However, I am able to create a geometry and edit it once in Civil 3D and save in the database (using check in and check out) but i am unable to make any further changes. I am working by connecting to the PostgreSQL connections in planning and analysis of Civil 3D workspace. I was wondering if anybody has faced the same issues in a similar type of workflow.

Comment: There is a bug in the FDO connections in Civil 3D causing the problem, it's inability to directly take id's from the database when editing/ adding. So, I am using a longer workflow of manually downloading the shape files in the local system, opening them in Civil 3D with MAPIMPORT (retain the id's) and then editing to load back into the database. This way, the previous id's are overwritten and new ones are added thereby not making copies of objects. Too bad i don't have an open source alternative to using Civil 3D.